# @font-face fails to work with custom WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face

I am working on WordPress with not-so-popular-and-profound theme. Its safe to say that its a totally custom theme. The problem I'm facing is about @font-face. I have working font-face construction here: http://akshay2000.pcriot.com/Trial/index1.html
I created same structure with my WordPress theme. It didn't work. Now, I have CSS as follows:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'SegoeWP-Light';
    src: url('segoewp-light.eot');
    src: url('segoewp-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('segoewp-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('segoewp-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('segoewp-light.svg#segoewp-light') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

The font files are in same directory as style.css and index.php. I'm using firebug for debugging. When I hover over individual *file name* (like segoewp-light.woff) firebug displays correct font. However, when I hover over font family name (which is 'SegoeWP-Light) I see regular serif font. Obviously, resultant font on site is serif font. I don't understand what is wrong. Same setup works for me on normal (non-WordPress) pages. I have also tried uploading fonts to a different serve and using absolute public URLs. That didn't work either.

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the font-face in your css?

Comment: the link you posted says "get away from here" and the source code has nothing.

Comment: @BillyMoat I wish to add class to elements like <h1> and give that class font-family. I don't think it matters though as hovering in firebug shows serif in CSS itself - mentioned above. @

Comment: Did you fix this? it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed about the path of font. I had WordPress hosted at http://indestructible.in/wp and subdomain http://blog.indestructible.in pointed to the directory. While CSS tried to load fonts on the subdomain, fonts were to be loaded from main domain. As pointed above, Firefox and IE need them to be on the same domain. (This might work in some cases but in my case, I have separate A records for main domain and subdomain. So, they might be treated differently.) This is why everything was okay when browser was pointed to the directory directly. What I did was, I created a totally new WordPress install on the subdomain and everything worked wonderfully!
**TL;DR:** Firefox and IE need @font-face fonts on the same domain and its always better to directly install WordPress on subdomain rather than pointing subdomain to the WordPress directory.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has something to do with your use of relative paths, but more information is needed, can you open your console and tell us what you see there as an error? Also, where are these files located in relation to your site root?

If your user is at `http://yoursite.com/blog/hello-world`, it's going to look for the font at `http://yoursite.com/blog/hello-world/segoewp-light.[ext]`

You may want to specify the absolute path of these files.

Comment: Here is the work I'm talking about: http://indestructible.in/wp. Console doesn't have any errors. Regarding absolute paths, as I mentioned, I tried uploading to totally different server and tried them using public URLs (http://akshay2000.pcriot.com/PublicDump/fonts) didn't help!

Comment: Looks like the font-family is misspelled (has spaces) in your css: `body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: segoe wp,segoe ui,verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color:#444;
}`
Your @font-face defines the family as "SegoeWP-Light" so use that exact string and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous! I was yet to add the font family. So, it did display the fonts correctly as they were installed on my machine. But now, I have given font-family: "SegoeWP-Light" to all headings in CSS and serif font is resulting. Ignoring all that stuff, isn't it odd that firebug doesn't give correct font after hovering in CSS itself! Something is wrong in CSS itself!

Comment: you said you uploaded them to a different server - that might cause you more problems because FF and IE both require @font-face fonts to be served from the same server as the whole website.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz No, its not fixed yet! It appears just fine in Chrome, Opera and Safari on iOS. While in IE and Firefox, serif font appears.

Comment: @imakeitpretty Well, as of now, they're on same server and same directory. And CSS reads as above. Works in Chrome, mobile Safari. Fails in Firefox and IE!

Comment: The problem is due to the reasons mentioned by @akshay2000 and imakeitpretty

Comment: @ajkochanowicz I don't get you. How do I fix those in Firefox and IE? Or is Firefox working fine already? I'm confused. It seems to both work and fail.

Comment: Can you not host this on the same server? That should fix it.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz They're hosted on same server and same directory! And I think I have isolated the problem. The thing is, I have created subdomain http://blog.indestructible.in When I visit the subdomain, fonts are not good in IE and FF. However, visiting the actual directory (http://indestructible.in/wp) works fine everywhere. Now, only if you could tell me how to solve that!

Comment: Ohhh. When you say "not good" do you mean they're not antialiased?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz Let me be clear for once and all. :) On pointing browser to _directory_ http://indestructible.in/wp everything works fine (ignoring anti-aliasing). However, if you go to _subdomain_ http://blog.indestructible.in , **serif** font is loaded on IE and FF. Rest of the browsers seem fine. Its probably the domain and path thing we talked about. But font is in same host-same directory. How do I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but this is what fontsquirrel has to say [Troubleshooting Font-Face Problems](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems).